# Deploy command line java application

Tags: java, deployment

I want to know how to distribute a java command line application. I am currently using Netbeans as my IDE. Please do not mention maven, I am still learning java. My application is built on NetBeans IDE. I download Inno and used NetBeans to create an installer for a Hello world program. After installing and running my application from command line its prints nothing.